# Official US term for a scientist or science

Tags: meaning, american-english

I am searching for the official or widely accepted US term for a scientist or science, which work on growing human organs in animals.

[Google search: growth of human organs in animals](https://www.google.si/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=growth+of+human+organs+in+animals&oq=growth+of+human+organs+in+animals&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30k1l2.1937.7780.0.8020.34.27.0.4.4.0.254.2942.11j12j1.24.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..6.27.2831.0..0j0i131k1j0i19k1j0i22i30i19k1.u1Q-5YXBR48)

I saw it in a documentary, erased it and have no idea if this would be acceptable for a logline:

> "A pregnant, growing human organ scientist turns unwanted homegrown terrorist…"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "organ scientist" isn't really in use. You might go for **"geneticist"**, or just a "biologist". This kind of research is part of the field of "biotech", and the specific term for growing human parts in a different species for transfer is "xenotransplantation".

Comment: – Thanks for all the data you have provided in your answer. “Geneticist” is a bit too soft for this sort of story and “xenotransplantation” is a tongue-breaker (a logline should flow like a poem when one reads it). 
It must be clear how far the consequences would go is something like this happens. 
I like biotech. That sounds fantastic. Would that be okay?
"A pregnant biotech scientist turns unwanted homegrown terrorist…"

Comment: Or better still, try "bioengineer"?

Comment: From four words down to one - a stroke of a genius. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help :)